# How to list all files those don't change since a specific GIT commit

Tags: git, git-log, gitlist

There is a big commit long ago in the past and a lot of change happened since then. How do I list all files those don't change of that commit up to now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following command chain:

```
git ls-files | grep -v "$(git diff --name-only <from-commit> <to-commit>)"
```

`git ls-files` lists all files which are under version control, while `git diff --name-only <from-commit> <to-commit>` will list the files which got changed in the specified commit range.

`grep -v` returns all lines which don't get matched by the given pattern (inverse match).

Hope that helps!

---

If you have problems with an `Argument list too long` error then you can use the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

git diff --name-only $1 $2 | {
    files="$(git ls-files)"

    while read line
    do
        files=$(echo "$files" | grep -v $line)
    done

    echo "$files"
}
```

This script will exclude one file path per iteration from the list of all files, so you should never experience the `Argument list too long` error.

You can use the script by saving it into a file and execute it with the commit hashes of the commit range whose files should be excluded from the result.

Comment: Thanks, it works for small commit, but for too big commit, grep throws `Argument list too long`.

Comment: @jwall I've edited the post with another way to accomplish the same thing. This should work for you.